# Arrays of template class objects

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, derived-class

## **Problem**

I would like an array of pointers to instances of a template class. My problem would be solved if C++ allowed templated virtual methods in a base class, with a templated derived class.

Therefore, how would one implement templated virtual methods?

Below I have a solution which seems to work, but I'm interested in comments about my implementation.

## **Constraints**

The template parameter is infinitely variable, e.g., I cannot enumerate every specialization of this template class. The template class `T` can be any POD, array of POD, or struct of POD.

The complete set of `T` is known at compile time. Basically, I have a file which defines all the different `T` used to instantiate the objects, and use Xmacros (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) to create the array of objects.

I know this isn't a great idea. Let's gloss over that for the time being. This ends up being more a curiosity.

## **Possible Solutions**

These are the things I've looked into.

### Create base and derived classes

```
class Base {
  virtual void SomeMethod() = 0;
}

template <class T>
class Derived : Base {
  void SomeMethod() {...}
}
```

The problem with this is I cannot declare all the virtual methods in `Base` that I want to overload, as virtual methods cannot be templated. Otherwise, it would be a perfect solution.

### std::any/std::variant

I am using C++17, so I could define the virtual base methods taking `std::any`. But it cannot hold arrays, which precludes its use here.

### CRTP

It seems this would not help me create an array of these different objects. I would need to do something like

```
template <typename D, typename T>
class Base
{
    ...
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base<Derived, T>
{
    ...
};
```

So I still end up with trying to create an array of `Derived<T>` objects.

### Visitor Pattern

Again it looks like I would need to enumerate every possible type the `Visitable` class needs to service, which, while not impossible (again, I have a file which defines all the different `T` that will be used) seems like more Xmacros, which is just making the problem more complicated.

## **My Solution**

This is what I came up with. It will run in https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <typeinfo>

// Base class which declares "overloaded" methods without implementation
class Base {
 public:
  template <class T>
  void Set(T inval);
  template <class T>
  void Get(T* retval);
  virtual void Print() = 0;
};

// Template class which implements the overloaded methods
template <class T>
class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  void Set(T inval) {
    storage = inval;
  }
  void Get(T* retval) {
    *retval = storage;
  }
  void Print() {
    std::cout << "This variable is type " << typeid(T).name() <<
      ", value: " << storage << std::endl;
  }
 private:
  T storage = {};
};

// Manually pointing base overloads to template methods
template <class T> void Base::Set(T inval) {
  static_cast<Derived<T>*>(this)->Set(inval);
}
template <class T> void Base::Get(T* retval) {
  std::cout << "CALLED THROUGH BASE!" << std::endl;
  static_cast<Derived<T>*>(this)->Get(retval);
}

int main()
{
  // Two new objects
  Derived<int>* ptr_int = new Derived<int>();
  Derived<double>* ptr_dbl = new Derived<double>();
  
  // Base pointer array
  std::array<Base*, 2> ptr_arr;
  ptr_arr[0] = ptr_int;
  ptr_arr[1] = ptr_dbl;

  // Load values into objects through calls to Base methods
  ptr_arr[0]->Set(3);
  ptr_arr[1]->Set(3.14);

  // Call true virtual Print() method
  for (auto& ptr : ptr_arr) ptr->Print();

  // Read out the values
  int var_int;
  double var_dbl;
  std::cout << "First calling Get() method through true pointer." << std::endl;
  ptr_int->Get(&var_int);
  ptr_dbl->Get(&var_dbl);
  std::cout << "Direct values: " << var_int << ", " << var_dbl << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Now calling Get() method through base pointer." << std::endl;
  ptr_arr[0]->Get(&var_int);
  ptr_arr[1]->Get(&var_dbl);
  std::cout << "Base values: " << var_int << ", " << var_dbl << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When this is run, it shows that calling the methods on `Base` correctly point to the `Derived` implementations.

```
This variable is type i, value: 3                                                                                                    
This variable is type d, value: 3.14                                                                                                 
First calling Get() method through true pointer.                                                                                     
Direct values: 3, 3.14                                                                                                               
Now calling Get() method through base pointer.                                                                                       
CALLED THROUGH BASE!                                                                                                                 
CALLED THROUGH BASE!                                                                                                                 
Base values: 3, 3.14
```

Essentially I am manually creating the virtual method pointers. But, since I am explicitly doing so, I am allowed to use template methods in `Base` which point to the methods in `Derived`. It is more prone to error, as for example for each template method I need to type the method name twice, i.e., I could mess up:

```
template <class T> void Base::BLAH_SOMETHING(T inval) {
  static_cast<Derived<T>*>(this)->WHOOPS_WRONG_CALL(inval);
}
```

So after all this, is this a terrible idea? To me it seems to achieve my objective of circumventing the limitation of templated virtual methods. Is there something really wrong with this? I understand there could be ways to structure the code that make all this unnecessary, I am just focusing on this specific construction.

Comment: Problem section is not description of problem, but description of solution you think is good. This is classic example of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please describe functionality you would like to achieve (possibly from end user point of view) - not way you which it could be implemented and I'm sure someone will propose simpler solution. Example: maybe you do not need single array, but multiple arrays one for each type.

Comment: My problem was "how to implement an array of templated class instances." The optimal solution is not to need an array of templated class instances, which I will eventually implement. However, in this case I got interested in this academic problem of how to "fake" templated virtual methods. So I re-specified my question.

Comment: Your problem should be something like: "As an end user I want to enter integer or floating point values and perform on them divide operation. In case both arguments are integral result should be integral otherwise result should be floating point." nothing about how it is implemented.

Comment: Note also how you are using this array in your code. You do not iterate over it, you do not search by index, you are using array with hard-coded indexes, so in practice you do not have an array, you have cells in array which are used as ordinary variables. This is proof that something is very bad with this code and it is not related to templates. I suspect you have  just read about those cool patterns (CRTP, polymorphism, variants) and you force your self to use them.

Comment: You have a self-contradictory set up. `Base` class object has generic methods (any T should work) but derived class object all have non-generic methods (only one T works for each object, namely the T which was used to instantiate its class). This cannot be consistently implemented in any language.

Comment: Your method lies about its applicability: it says `template<T>` but it can only be ever called with a single argument type. Your `static_cast<Derived<T>*>` essentially says "I know  I have a `Derived<T>` here, I promise, honest" even though there is no guarantee whatsoever and it isn't clear how the user of this method is expected to know that. You might know that when you are a single user and you have a `main` with two pointers and a total of 3 lines that separate creation from usage. This is unsustainable in real software.

Comment: The code example was just to see it working. In reality, I currently have 60-70 instances of `Derived<long/double>` doing a bunch of math. The base class contains virtual `Stats()` method that returns statistics on the running calculations. There is an array of `Base*` over which I iterate to periodically samples the output of `Stats()` to tweak the calculation parameters. I am interested in 2 things: (1) extending to arbitrary types `T` e.g., arrays and structs, and (2) accessing samples of `T` through the base class array (latter just curiosity, I don't absolutely need to).

Comment: This is interesting and all, but your explanations do not even attempt to address the problem. *How do you know* which type is really there? If you know by some kind of magic that `Derived1<int>` is at index 0 and `Derived52<float>` is at index 2, why do you put them in the same array in the first place?

Comment: I have a map from string names to `Base*`. So I know the names of all these instances and what they contain. The ability to access the underling `T` of each object from a single map (or array, as I put in the code example) would just be for convenience while writing the code, and not actually necessary for the functionality of the code. I just got interested in how one would go about solving this particular problem as stated, as it is not actually a gating problem.

Answer (score 1):

> It is more prone to error, as for example for each template method I need to type the method name twice

Oh, that's the least of your concerns. Imagine if you downcast to the wrong type.

At least save yourself a headache and use `dynamic_cast`:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    template <class T>
    void Set(T inval) {
        dynamic_cast<Derived<T>&>(*this).Set(inval);
    }

    template <class T>
    T Get() {
        return dynamic_cast<Derived<T>&>(*this).Get();
    }
};


template <class T>
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    void Set(T inval) {
      storage = inval;
    }

    T Get() {
      return storage;
    }

  private:
    T storage{};
};
```

Other than that, I agree with the comments, this is probably not the right approach to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The normal run-off-the-mill method of dealing with subclasses that contain unknown types is to move the entire thing to a virtual function. Thus, instead of

```
superclass->get_value(&variable_of_unknown_type);
print(variable_of_unknown_type);
```

you write

```
superclass->print_value();
```

Now you don't need to know about any of the types a subclass might contain.

This is not always appropriate though, because there could be lots of operations. Making every operation a virtual function is troublesome if you are adding new operations all the time. On the other hand, the set of possible subclasses is often limited. In this case your best bet is the [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Visitor rotates the inheritance hierarchy 90°, so to speak. Instead of fixing the set of operations and adding new subclasses freely, you fix the set of subclasses and add new operations freely. So instead of

```
superclass->print_value();
```

you write

```
class PrinterVisitor : public MyVisitor
{
   virtual void processSubclass1(Subclass1* s) { print(s->double_value); }
   virtual void processSubclass2(Subclass2* s) { print(s->int_value); }
};

superclass->accept(PrinterVisitor());
```

Now `accept` is the only `virtual` function in your base class. Note there are no casts that could possibly fail anywhere in the code.